# Are we getting notified when swag has been shipped?

Tags: support, 10m-questions-milestone

I was wondering if the ones who won swag for the 10m question milestone are getting notified when the swag has been shipped.

Comment: I've received several shipments of swag over the years, I was never notified that something was shipped. The joy of the package arriving is all the greater for it!

Comment: Well, I know that. The thing is I'm outside the states working on a project. So a relative is receiving the package. If I knew an approximate date of delivery I could plan my visit accordingly and visit my family plus get the swag @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: It's not much of a joy if you're not there to receive it, though...

Comment: I didn't choose the abroad working life, the abroad working life chose me @BoltClock

Comment: I don't need to track it, just to know when it's shipped @KyleMit

Comment: Sure, your doorbell is apt to ring.  You won't have to wait long after that.

Comment: Possibly Tim Post could at least confirm whether any/all swag has been shipped yet. You could ping him in [this chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: I don't know but I hope it ships soon. I haven't left the front steps for 2 weeks!

Comment: So... Somebody please update here somewhere, if they get the shipment! ;)

Comment: Are other people still waiting for packages? Or is it just me?

Comment: Still waiting as well @ErinGoBragh :'(

Comment: Still waiting..

Comment: [What happened to that contest swag I was promised?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised)

Comment: I got mine around the 3rd week of december